# Application Error when deploying flask app on azure app service

Tags: azure, rest, flask, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

this is the "app.py" file in the Github repository.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


# LUIS_Intent
from azure.cognitiveservices.language.luis.runtime import LUISRuntimeClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials
import json

# Entity
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.textanalytics import TextAnalyticsClient



class Intent_EU_Taxo(Resource):
    def get(self, sentence):
        predictionKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' 
        predictionEndpoint = 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.cognitiveservices.azure.com/'
        app_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

        runtimeCredentials = CognitiveServicesCredentials(predictionKey)
        clientRuntime = LUISRuntimeClient(endpoint=predictionEndpoint, credentials=runtimeCredentials)

        predictionRequest = { "query" : sentence}

        predictionResponse = clientRuntime.prediction.get_slot_prediction(app_id, "Production", predictionRequest)
        top_intent_score = predictionResponse.prediction.intents[predictionResponse.prediction.top_intent].score

        return jsonify({'type': predictionResponse.prediction.top_intent, 'score': top_intent_score})


class Orga_Entity(Resource):
    def get(self, sentence):
        credential = AzureKeyCredential("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
        text_analytics_client = TextAnalyticsClient(endpoint="https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.cognitiveservices.azure.com/", credential=credential)

        documents = [sentence]

        response = text_analytics_client.recognize_entities(documents, language="de")
        result = [doc for doc in response if not doc.is_error]
        entity_list = []


        for doc in result:
            for entity in doc.entities:
                if entity.category == "Organization" and entity.confidence_score >= 0.5:
                    entity_list.append(entity.text)
                else:
                    pass

        return jsonify({'Company': entity_list[0]})


api.add_resource(Intent_EU_Taxo, '/intent/<sentence>')
api.add_resource(Orga_Entity, '/entity/<sentence>')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is how my github folder looks like.

[The Github looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiIsQ.jpg)

This is in the requirements.txt file in the github repository:

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-restful==0.3.9
azure-ai-textanalytics==5.1.0
azure-cognitiveservices-language-luis==0.7.0
msrest==0.7.1
azure-core==1.24.2
azure-ai-textanalytics==5.1.0
```

I deploy this github repository to the azure app service with python 3.9 runtime. The deployment looks fine.

[deploy from github on azure app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKdbt.jpg)

However, when I test it like "http://XXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/entity/"EU Taxo check für Siemens", it does not return the json result which I get in the local deployment.

Local deployment:
[local deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bh6k.jpg)

Deployment on Azure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2Rr6.jpg)

I google a lot, but doesn't know what's wrong with my deployment....
I am very new to flask app and azure app service, please forgive me if it looks stupid. Thanks for every tips!

Comment: Application errors is a generic error message and this might be caused due to multiple reasons.

I would suggest you to enable Enabling log streaming in app service to identify the error your logs files or you can run the Diagnostic and solve problems which can help you to identify the cause.